# Parsing object with arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using Google's Natural Language API and it's working fine and returning data. I'm just not able to parse it correctly. I'd like to form a JSON object I can then use with AJAX or similar. What I need out of this are mainly the sentences and their sentiment. I'm struggling with this object that I get back:

```
    object(Google\Cloud\NaturalLanguage\Annotation)#21 (1) {
  ["info":"Google\Cloud\NaturalLanguage\Annotation":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["documentSentiment"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["magnitude"]=>
      float(1.4)
      ["score"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["language"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["sentences"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["content"]=>
          string(19) "I love everything!\"
          ["beginOffset"]=>
          int(0)
        }
        ["sentiment"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["magnitude"]=>
          float(0.8)
          ["score"]=>
          float(0.8)
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["content"]=>
          string(18) "I hate everything!"
          ["beginOffset"]=>
          int(21)
        }
        ["sentiment"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["magnitude"]=>
          float(0.6)
          ["score"]=>
          float(-0.6)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ADDED:

The very last bit of my PHP code is:

```
$annotation = $language->analyzeSentiment($text);
$sentiment = $annotation->sentiment();
echo 'Text: ' . $text . '
Sentiment: ' . $sentiment['score'] . ', ' . $sentiment['magnitude'];
return $sentiment;
```

This successfully returns the score and magnitude for the overall "document" as shown in the part of the array under `"documentSentiment"`. What I need (in addition to this), is the data under `sentences`. In particular, `content`, `magnitude` and `score`.

Comment: can you show an example of what you want to get, in the desired format. It would then be easier to look at how to build the code structure to get there.

Comment: @Sean Thanks...added some more detail that I think might help.

Comment: Using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` you can create a json feed out of an array. I'm not sure if that's what you want tough.

Comment: Since `sentences` is an array, you need to loop over the array to get the values from the `content`, `magnitude`, and `score`.

Comment: @Nicolas I tried that, but couldn't figure out what to actually `json_encode()`, so never got a good feed.

Comment: @jonmrich well this is up to what you need. we can't figure out the algo for you, create an array of what you want then encode it.

Comment: @jonmrich oh and by the way, if you are having problem with std_object, you can simple cast them into arrays : `$array = (array)$my_Object;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$sentiment['sentences']` is an array -

```
["sentences"]=>
    array(2) {
        ...
    }
```

you need to loop over the values, with `foreach()` for example -

```
....  
echo 'Text: ' . $text . '
Sentiment: ' . $sentiment['score'] . ', ' . $sentiment['magnitude'];

foreach($sentiment['sentences'] as $sentence){
    echo 'Text: ' .$sentence["text"]["content"] . '
    Sentiment: ' . $sentence["sentiment"]["score"] . ', ' . $sentence["sentiment"]["magnitude"];
}
```